# how can i call archive-{post type}.php template from my custom plugins to my theams?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, archive-template

first I create **plugins/bike/archive-bike.php** in plugins directory

```
<?php get_header();  
     get_sidebar();
?>
<div class="container">
    <?php 
         echo "test";
    ?>
</div>
<?php  get_footer();?>
```

and then add filter in **plugins/bike/bike.php**

```
<?php
function load_archive_bike_template( $template ) {
    global $post;
    
    if ( 'bike' === $post->post_type && locate_template( array( 'archive-bike' ) ) !== $template ) {
        /*
         * This is a 'bike' post
         * AND a 'archive bike template' is not found on
         * theme or child theme directories, so load it
         * from our plugin directory.
         */
        return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'archive-bike.php';
    
    }
  
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'archive_template', 'load_archive_bike_template' );
?>
```

now i need to call this into the frontend means in custom themes so i make one link to the **sidebar.php**

```
<a href="<?php echo get_post_type_archive_link( 'bike' ); ?>" class="sidebar-info">new bikes </a>
get_post_type_archive_link('bike')
```

redirect me in this link when I click on **new bike** `http://localhost/wordpress/bike/`
Can anybody please help me, what I was missing in my code or at the admin panel. ):

Comment: Please be aware that WordPress themes are not very standardised, so any archive template you attempt to serve from a plugin is almost certainly going to look ugly and broken in most themes.